# Collection View Cell for iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, cell, collectionview

Is there any way to automatically assign a Collection View Cell's identifier? I have a few hundred cells that are all giving me the "cells must have reuse identifiers" warning and I don't want to go assign them each one by hand...

Comment: Why do you have so many prototyped cells? I'm assuming you have a identifier cell that your using already?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, as long as all of your cells are the same class, you should be able to do something like this before setting them up:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[Cell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
```